# Application Level High Availability Library for .NET

Tags: .net, cluster-computing, high-availability

I'm looking for an application level High Availability (HA or Cluster) library for .NET / C#.

MSCS is not a solution for me since i need to have full control over clustered instances of my application.

Any help ?

Comment: What kind of load balancing are you using?

Comment: Manual load balancing logic, since classic load balancing method isn't enough for me

Comment: In what ways is 'classic' load balancing insufficient?  We can't provide meaningful answers without knowing what the requirements are.

Comment: classic load balancing act at network level (IP), I need a load balancing solution working at application level, with custom logic based on some custom data, not network or memory/cpu

Comment: plus, i need a clustering/load balancing mechanism which can "re-load-balance" some work on the fly when new or dead servers goes up

Answer (score 0):

You can use Windows Azure to do something similar. What it does it preserves state of the app (via session like mechanism) and can restart app on another server when original is crashed, as well it can start your apps on additional machines.
Currently Microsoft doesn't sell azure appliances or software yet and at the moment there is no other mechanism like switching app runtimes on the fly, messaging is what is available at most.
Still, by having state saved into the clustered storage or database, you can restart app to the same point on the another machine.
You can make it yourself as well, but design would depend on how many instances you can allocate and what operating systems you want to use.